# Getting time from a string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would need to convert strings like `- n days +hh:mm:ss` to `-1*n*hh:mm:ss` where `n` is the number of days.

This means that if I have `-1 days +20:07:00` I should have `-20:07`; if I have `-1 days +03:24:58` I should have `-03:24` , and so on.

I have tried with

```
name = "days"


s = df['Time'].str.extract(f'(\d+) ({"|".join(name)})')[0].astype(float) 
s *= 24
df['New_time'] = np.where(s.notna(),s.apply(lambda x:'{:.02f}'.format(x)), 
                        df['Time'])
df['New_time'] =df['New_time'].str.replace('.',':')
```

But I think I have missed something as the output gives me

```
                                                          Time           New_time  
Names                                                                          
CERVETERI Archivi                                     -1 days +20:07:00     21:00  
Cetto la qualunque...                                 -1 days +22:02:00     19:00   
La vita è bella ..                                             00:07:00     17:00                   Vita da cani                                                       02:12:00     15:00
```

The expected output should be

```
                                                          Time           New_time  
Names                                                                          
CERVETERI Archivi                                     -1 days +20:07:00     -20:07  
Cetto la qualunque...                                 -1 days +22:02:00     -22:02  
La vita è bella ..                                             00:07:00     00:07                   Vita da cani                                                       02:12:00     02:12
```

Currently `df['Time']` is `dtype('O')`.

Could you please help me to spot the errors? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bit long and not elegant. but works for your examples.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def calculate(dayString):

    parts = dayString.split()
    sign = ""

    if(len(parts) != 3):
        time = datetime.strptime(parts[0][1:], "%H:%M:%S")
    else:
        days = int(parts[0])
        if(days < 0):
            sign = "-"
        time = datetime.strptime(
            parts[2][1:], "%H:%M:%S") + timedelta(days=days)

    time = sign + time.strftime("%H:%M")
    return time

data = {'Time': ['-1 days +20:07:00', '-1 days +22:02:00', '00:07:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Time'])
df['New_time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: calculate(x))
print(df)
```

```
                Time New_time
0  -1 days +20:07:00   -20:07
1  -1 days +22:02:00   -22:02
2           00:07:00    00:07
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly, but works:

```
df['New_Time'] = df.Time.str.split().\
apply(lambda x: str(int(x[2].split(':')[0].strip('+'))\
-int(x[0])*24)+x[2][3:])
```

output:

```
                Time  New_Time
0  -1 days +20:07:00  44:07:00
1  -1 days +22:02:00  46:02:00
```

Comment: Sorry Binyamin. I had to fix the formula and the code as I noticed that the Time was already calculated with 24 hours.Couuld you please have a look at the updated question? sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I think I should do something like if rows contains `- n days + ....` then add a `-` . I would need to plot this values (I hope this can work). Thanks and sorry again for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

So to the second version..

```
df['New_Time'] = df.Time.str.split().\
apply(lambda x: '-'+':'.join(x[2].split(':')[0:2])[1:]\
if x[0].startswith('-') else ':'.join(x[2].split(':')[0:2])[1:])
```

Comment: no need for two posts, just add this to your original answer